# Lack of Logical Right Shift in Python

Tags: python, bit-shift

Why doesn't Python have logical right shift? I heard that it's either because Python doesn't have a fixed number of bits for it's integers or because there are no unsigned integers in Python or because it doesn't make sense to have it for high level languages.

Comment: Python does have a right shift (see for instance `hex(0x100 >> 1)`). Is that what you want?

Comment: that's an arithmetic right shift. If I do -1>>2, I get -1

Comment: Python uses 64-bit `long`s for integers, not variable length, doesn't it?

Comment: You pretty much covered all the answers in your question.

Comment: Yes, those are the reasons.  Even in python2, which uses fixed with integers, it is expected that the width is an implementation detail. So a logical right shift on a negative number doesn't have an obvious meaning

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. `0b00000000000000000000000000001000 >> 2` works just fine. I haven't tested 64-bit, though.

Comment: @JessicaGu I was very surprised at `-1 >> 2`. `-1 >> 10000` gives the same result. Its like python is doing division and then rounding down. To me, there is no such thing as a negative number in "logical" operations so the question is somewhat moot. Considering all the strange edge conditions with unsigned numbers (e.g., logical shift of signed 2s compliment number) I can see why its not in python.